# Jquery, ajax and problem with load

Tags: php, jquery

This is the HTML part:

```
div id="messages">
   <div class="messages">


<?php if(isset ($unread)) { ?>
   <p>You have <?php echo $unread?> unread messages.</p>
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(isset ($messages)) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $msg){ ?>
      <div class="col_3">             
<?php     
      if($msg['read'] == 0){ echo 'Status of message: Unreaded';}
      elseif($msg['read'] == 1){echo 'Status of message: Readed';}
     echo "<p>Message from: $msg[name]</p>";
     echo "<p>Sender email: $msg[email]</p>";        
     echo "<p>Message: <br />$msg[message]</p>"; ?>
     <a href="#" class="delete" id="<?php echo $msg['id'] ?>">Delete message</a>
      </div>
 <?php } ?>                
<?php } ?><!-------- end of if $message-------->
       </div><!------ end of div .messages--------->
   </div><!------ end of div #messages--------->
```

and JQ:

```
  $(".delete").click(function() {    
    var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");            
    var string = 'id='+ id ;
    $.ajax({   
        url: "<?php echo site_url('messages/delete') ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: string,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            commentContainer.slideUp('600', function() {$(this).remove();
                $('.messages').fadeOut('2000', function(){$(this).remove();
                    $('#messages').load("<?php echo site_url('messages/show') ?>");
                }); 
            });               
        }   
    });
    return false;
});
```

Code is working, but when it comes to the load nothing is being shown. I did

```
load("<?php echo site_url('messages/show') ?>", function() {
```

alert('Load was performed.');
});

and there was an alert, and when I look page source I can see that the content has been changed, but it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you view the source of a page that has been loaded via AJAX, it will never update. You will need to inspect the DOM in order to see what has changed.

The reason is because the content is not actually on the page and is being dynamically added to the page.

Comment: I am quite new to the JS and JQ, so I am little lost. How can I do that?

Comment: If you are using FireFox, Google Chrome or Opera. you can right click on the page and in the menu, click "Inspect Element" this will bring up the DOM and show you all the "Live" changes to the source. In IE9/8 you can press F12 to bring up a developers panel. Safari? who knows...

Comment: In Safari, you need to go into the preferences settings > Advanced > then tick "Show Develop menu in menu bar". Then when you right click you can see "Insepect Element"

Comment: Hmm, didn't have that in mind. Thank you for the tips :). What I had in mind is how to present data? I installed firebug and upon deleting message I got post request (it is ok) and after that there is get request with following response: `<div class="messages">
<!-------- end of if $message-------->
</div>`.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I inspected the problem and found solution. Thank you :)

Comment: One quick question. When everything is loaded, and new data is shown delete function is lost (` <a href="#" class="delete" id="<?php echo $msg['id'] ?>">Delete message</a>` is not working). How can i fix this?

Comment: You will either need to bind a new click event to the `.delete` class, or use the `live` function in jquery http://api.jquery.com/live/